# Is the rvalue passed to the function still rvalue or not?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, value-categories

I'm trying to understand everything I can about transfer semantics, rvalue, xvalue, prvalue, etc.
I have the following function:

```cpp
void f(int&& x, int i)
{
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>().pretty_name();
}
```

Then I get the output: `int&&`

Good. So, `x`, even inside function, is an rvalue reference?

The `boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr` function suggests that, even within the function, input rvalue reference parameter is still an rvalue reference.
However, from what I read on the internet, the rvalue passed to the function, inside the function, becomes lvalue reference.

> the rvalue reference from the parameter is only used to select the function from the caller's perspective, it behaves like an lvalue reference inside the function

[is rvalue passed as parameter treated as lvalue inside the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062853/)

And so, when inside function `f`, I've tried to call function `f` again; suddenly it turned out that `x` is no longer an rvalue at all:

```cpp
void f(int&& x, int i)
{
     std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>().pretty_name();
     i++;
     if (i < 10)
     {
         f(x, i);
     }
}
```

```
int main(int, char**)
{
     int i = 0;
     f(50,i);
}
```

Result: "cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’".

So what is the type of x inside a function after all, and who is wrong here?

I thought this:

1. `50` is an rvalue and evaluating the expression `50` returns an rvalue reference
2. rvalue reference `int&& x` is an lvalue and therefore returns lvalue reference (?)

Is this the correct way of reasoning?

Or is the boost library wrong? Or maybe is compiler returning a bad error?
Why in error massage is lvalue of type `int` and not `int&`?

If the parameter behaves as an lvalue reference inside the function (as it says in the stack thread I linked), why doesn't the error say `int&`?

And I don't mean just to get the answer what is the type of `x` inside the function. I'm more interested in understanding why the boost library says one thing, the error says something else, and the theoretical knowledge of C++ says something else.

Comment: Generally, once something have a "name" it's an lvalue. For the argument `x`, you can pass an rvalue to the function, but inside the function itself `x` is an lvalue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a named rvalue reference "ref" a xvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039351/is-a-named-rvalue-reference-ref-a-xvalue)

Comment: @ChrisMM That (or some other post) is most probably a duplicate but I can't see a really good explanation in there that the `x` **as an argument** has a type of `int&&` but, once used **in an expression** is a plain `int` (lvalue). (But my explanation is garbled and not good, I think.)

Comment: Rvalues and rvalue references are different things. [Expressions can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1). If you want to know the value category (i.e. the former), you need `decltype((x))`, not `decltype(x)`.

Comment: There's a nice Q/A somewhere (IIRC) about the nature of the argument to a move c'tor *inside* that c'tor. ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is rvalue passed as parameter treated as lvalue inside the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062853/is-rvalue-passed-as-parameter-treated-as-lvalue-inside-the-function)

Comment: @JerryCoffin that doesn't make sense. Lvalues don't refer to rvalues. Value categories are a property of a single expression.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two separate concepts, and are getting royally confused.

- declarations can be references (such as lvalue ref., rvalue ref.)

  - for example, the parameter `x` inside `f` is an rvalue reference, because it is declared as such
- expressions have value categories (lvalue, xvalue, prvalue)

  - for example, the expression `x` when it appears inside `f` is an lvalue (unless it is located in a `return` statement)

`x` is an rvalue reference when talking about the function parameter, but `x` is an lvalue when talking about the expression as it appears in other code. When you understand the difference, all your questions are easy to answer:

> Good. So, `x`, even inside function, is an rvalue reference?

Yes, the parameter `x` of the function `f` is an rvalue reference.
That's exactly what `decltype(x)` gives you: the *declared type*, as the name suggests.

> However, from what I read on the internet, the rvalue passed to the function, inside the function, becomes lvalue reference.

This is inaccurate. The function parameters are lvalues when they appear in an some expression, but what type they have depends entirely on how you've declared the function. For example:

```cpp
void foo(int x) {
    x;            // lvalue
    std::move(x); // xvalue
    int{x};       // prvalue
    // note: these three categorizations are exactly the same,
    //       no matter whether the type of x is an object, lvalue ref., or rvalue ref.
}

int y = ...;
foo(y);            // pass an lvalue of type int to foo()
foo(std::move(y)); // pass an xvalue of type int to foo()
foo(50);           // pass a prvalue of type int to foo()
```

> So what is the type of `x` inside a function after all, and who is wrong here?

The type of the expression `x` is `int`, and the value category of the expression `x` is lvalue. The type of the function parameter `x` is `int&&`.

> `50` is an rvalue and evaluating the expression `50` returns an rvalue reference

`50` is a prvalue, but evaluating it doesn't produce a reference. It produces a temporary object of type `int`.

> rvalue reference `int&& x` is an lvalue and therefore returns lvalue reference (?)

That sentence doesn't make sense. A type isn't inherently an lvalue or rvalue.
The value category depends on the expression and the context in which `x` is used.

> If the parameter behaves as an lvalue reference inside the function (as it says in the stack thread I linked), why doesn't the error say `int&`?

Because the type of the parameter `x` is `int&&`. If you use `decltype`, that's exactly what it tells you.

> And I don't mean just to get the answer what is the type of `x` inside the function. I'm more interested in understanding why the boost library says one thing, the error says something else, and the theoretical knowledge of C++ says something else.

The type of the parameter `x` is `int&&`, and the type of the expression `x` is `int`.
The boost utility you're using works based on the type of the parameter, not based n the type of an expression `x`.

If you wanted to, you could obtain the type of the expression `x` be with:

```cpp
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(x)>
```

This is obviously different from `decltype(x)`, which yields the type of the declaration.